# Redshift / MySQL - Checking for non-equality between 2 integer columns returns the wrong result

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I am querying some results on Redshift and stumbled upon what seems like a bug when I check for non-equality between 2 integer columns, when some of the results have NULL values for one of the columns.

Here is a simple test:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 1 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 2 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, NULL AS dest
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE orig != dest
```

I obviously expect the result to be `2`, but it prints `1`.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Thanks

EDIT: Just checked on MySQL, I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null is considered as  an unknown value.When you compare `1 != null` the result is evaluated to false.

Hence the the result is 1 in your case where `1 != 2`

Comment: If someone wants more detail on this nonsense: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/

Comment: Nulls are a nuisance

Answer (score 1):

Both mysql and redshift offer the `COALESCE` function which can be used where null values may exist. this query will give you your expected result.

```
-- 9999999 value used below is a value sure not to exist in other table.
-- can be 0 or any value you choose based on your a prioiri knowledge of the data

WITH test AS (
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 1 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 2 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, NULL AS dest
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE orig != COALESCE(dest,999999999)
```

Comment: I considered using that but you never know if `999999999` will be a valid ID or not. I guess that 0 is a better choice since IDs start at 1.

Comment: @AntoineB as stated in the comment in my code snippet -  Can be any value you choose based on your a prioiri knowledge of the data

Comment: Ah yeah indeed, my bad, I didn't look closely enough :)

Answer (score 0):

As VK_217 said, it is due to the fact that NULL is not considered as a value and cannot be compared to an existing value, hence any kind of comparison will return NULL (and will, consequently, not match your WHERE clause).

You can find more details about the behaviour in this article: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/

If you need to have the expected behaviour, here is what I ended up using:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 1 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, 2 AS dest UNION
    SELECT 1 AS orig, NULL AS dest
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE (
    (orig IS NULL AND dest IS NOT NULL)
    OR
    (orig IS NOT NULL AND dest IS NULL)
    OR
    (orig != dest)
)
```